# Importing package after running setup.py does not work

Tags: python-2.7, setup.py, egg

I have the following file structure:

```
setup.py  
src/  
    __init__.py
    source.py
```

My `setup.py` file contains:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name = "PackageName",
    version = "0.0",
    author = "My Name",
    description = "Something",
    packages = ['src']
)
```

However when I run the command:

`>python setup.py install`

The installation runs without any error, but in the `Python27\Lib\site-packages` directory where all installed packages go, I only see a `.egg` file. Furthermore, I cannot use the `import PackageName` command as I get the error that the package does not exist. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why did you decide to call your package "src"?

Comment: No reason in particular. It contained the source files.

Comment: Why wouldn't you give it the name you actually want the package to have?

Comment: I thought that was what the "name" attribute was for.

Comment: So I changed the package name from `src` to `PackageName` and it worked. I am not sure if it was because `src` is reserved or if the "name" attribute has to match the package name.

Answer (score 0):

The name used for importing in `import PackageName` should be the name of the package directory. So changing `src` to `PackageName` will resolve the import error.

Thanks to  @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams for pointing this out.